# Docker Desktop uunable to start due to unhandled exception occured in your application

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

So, Docker was running fine until few days ago. And suddenly it won't even start now.
This is the error I get while trying to start Docker Desktop.

**Exception Text
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Docker.Core.Features.Features.d__16.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\master-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Features\Features.cs:line 91
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.App.d__28.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\master-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\App.cs:line 114
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.Core.TaskExtension.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\master-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Extensions.cs:line 30
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()**

[This is the error that displays.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSh4Q.png)